# Bash script delete file inside another folder if not present in both

Tags: bash

The goal of the script is to check to see if a filename exists inside a folder. If the file name does NOT exist, then delete the file.

This is the script I got so far

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "What's the folder name?"
read folderName
$fileLocation="/home/daniel/Dropbox/Code/Python/FR/alignedImages/$folderName"

for files in "/home/daniel/Dropbox/Code/Python/FR/trainingImages/$folderName"/*
do
  fileNameWithFormatFiles=${files##*$folderName/}
  fileNameFiles=${fileNameWithFormat%%.png*}
  for entry in "/home/daniel/Dropbox/Code/Python/FR/alignedImages/$folderName"/*
  do
    fileNameWithFormat=${entry##*$folderName/}
    fileName=${fileNameWithFormat%%.png*}
    if [ -f "/home/daniel/Dropbox/Code/Python/FR/alignedImages/$fileNameFiles.jpg" ]
    then
      echo "Found File"
    else
      echo $files
      rm -f $files
    fi
  done
done
read
```

I have two folders, `alignedImages` and `trainingImages`.

All of the images in `alignedImages` will be inside `trainingImages`, but not the otherway around. So, I'm trying to make it so that if `trainingImages` does not contain a file with the same name as the file in `alignedImages`, then I want it to delete the file in `trainingImages`.

Also, the pictures are not the same, so I can't just compare md5's or hashes or whatever. Just the file names would be the same, except they are .jpg instead of .png

Comment: One quick thing: you don't include the `$` when assigning to a variable.

Comment: @mooiamaduck Good looking out

Answer (score 2):

```
fileLocation="/home/daniel/Dropbox/Code/Python/FR/alignedImages/$folderName"
echo "What's the folder name?"
read folderName

 rsync --delete --ignore-existing $fileLocation $folderName
```

`rsync` command is what you are looking for and when given the `--delete` option it will delete from destination dir any file that doesn't exist in source dir and `--ignore-existing` will cause rsync skip copying files from source if a file with same name already exist in destination dir.

The side effect of this is that it would copy any file in source dir but not in destination. You say all files in source are in destination so I guess that's ok

Comment: This would be great but I meant that only the file names would in there, not the actual pictures. So I can't exactly have it syncing them both up =/

Answer (score 1):

there is a better way! files, not `for` loops!

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "What's the folder name?"
read folderName

cd "/home/daniel/Dropbox/Code/Python/FR/alignedImages/$folderName"
find . -type f -name "*.png" | sed 's/\.png//' > /tmp/align.list

cd "/home/daniel/Dropbox/Code/Python/FR/trainingImages/$folderName"
find . -type f -name "*.jpg" | sed 's/\.jpg//' > /tmp/train.list
```

here's how to find files in both lists:

```
fgrep -f /tmp/align.list /tmp/train.list | sed 's/.*/&.jpg/' > /tmp/train_and_align.list
```

`fgrep -v` finds non-matches instead of matches: find files in train but not align:

```
fgrep -v -f /tmp/align.list /tmp/train.list | sed 's/.*/&.jpg/' > /tmp/train_not_align.list
```

test delete of all files in train_not_align.list:

```
cd "/home/daniel/Dropbox/Code/Python/FR/trainingImages/$folderName"
cat /tmp/train_not_align.list | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 echo rm -f
```

(if this produces good output, remove the `echo` statement to actually delete those files.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I have a bit of an issue though. In terminal I get `grep: align.list: No such file or directory
grep: align.list: No such file or directory
` Which is weird, because when I look inside my /tmp/ folder. I see those files

Comment: I fixed it by adding `/tmp/` in front of them.

Comment: Welp. It deleted everything inside the `trainingImages`. So... that's unfortunate =/

Comment: ugh. so sorry. i left the `-v` off of the condensed command (fixed now), causing it to delete from the train AND align list instead of the train NOT align list. i hope that you can recover them: https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/296

Comment: Hey man! No problem! Yeah, I made duplicates. and it's all good! You've already helped me so much lol. The thing is that I wasn't using the condensed version :P I'll try it with the condensed version and see how it goes!

Comment: ugh there was another bug, present in both versions. i've fixed it, simplified it, and tested the exact code. (i had previously tested only parts of the code.) apologies. i hope that you will fault me and not the method, because this really is a good way of quickly comparing and processing parallel lists of files. also, here are two tips: 1. look at the temporary files after each step to make sure they contain what's expected, and 2. try a dry-run with `xargs -0 echo rm -f` first, to see which files `xargs -0 rm -f` would `rm`.

Comment: Lmao, I have no idea why you hate me. It still ended up deleting everything lmao.

Comment: it's not you. the png industry is blackmailing me to sabotage jpegs.

Comment: in seriousness, i don't know why this deleted everything. how would you characterize the contents of the four temp files?

Comment: Unfortunately, it consumes a lot of memory/RAM for big files (> 50 MB). And: Error: `grep: Unmatched [ or [^` -> You should add `-F` (in addition to `-f <FILE>` and `-v`) if there are strange characters in the file paths, such as `[`.